# Visual Studio 2019 Diagnostic Tools for Xamarin Forms Project Not Supported?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019

Diagnostic tools were running previously, but I closed the window (and probably disabled in the options also) because I didn't need it at the time.

Now I've re-enabled it and it seems to not be working anymore. I get the following message. Any ideas how to get it back? I'm debugging a Xamarin Forms Android app.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I reproduce the error.

[image]

You could set the `Attaching to Process`, which is what ended up working. `Debug > Attach to Process`, which opens up a window that lists a large number of available processes. You could search in `Available processes` to find the device. I use Android emulator for test. My emulator device process is `qemu-system-i386.exe`. If you do not make sure the process of device, you could check on Task Manager.

[image]

After `Attach`, you could use the `diagnostic tools` in Xamarin.forms Android project.

[image]

**Updated:**

[image]

Comment: This appears to work at first, but it then crashes my machine.

Comment: Does it always crash? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: Do not forget to run as admin.

Comment: My machine completely crashed--twice. Stop Code: SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION What failed: IntelHaxm.sys

Comment: After attaching, as you suggested, and debugging, my machine ends up crashing with a blue screen.

Comment: Umm...How about restart your computer? Do you get the blue screen before? If no, maybe this error caused by the Visual Studio. Reinstall the VS maybe could fix the error.

Comment: This is measuring a combination of all the processing on the emulator - it is equivalent to looking at Task Manager > Performance on windows. You're seeing the emulator use its allocated 1 gb of computer memory. Also the console will show all the emulator's system logs instead of just your app.